# Correct way to parse arguments using ARGV

Tags: ruby, argv

I've written a program that uses `ARGV` as the arguments, due to me not being able to install external gems.

What I'm doing so far is this:

```
if ARGV[0] == '-h'
  puts "Help page"
elsif ARGV[0] == '--example'
  puts "Examples page"
elsif ARGV[0] == '-t'
  puts "Gathering intel"
elsif ARGV[0] == '--version'
  puts "Version mode"
elsif ARGV[0] == '--dev-mode'
  puts "developer mode"
else
  puts "Help page"
end
```

This doesn't seem idiomatic to me. So my question is, is there a correct way to parse `ARGV` arguments from a Ruby script? I've done some research and seen people using `ARGV.shift` and such, is this "preferred" in the Ruby world?

Comment: This way you'll have a big list if the set of your options is really big. Besides, may be a bit complicated to maintain such code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`OptionParser`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) might be the right choice for possibly complicated parameters list.

Regarding your code, I would rewrite it that way:

```
puts case ARGV[0]
     when '-h' then "Help page"
     when '--example' then "Examples page"
     ...
     end
```

Here is a DRY principle taken into account: one `puts`, since each branch does `puts`, `ARGV[0]` mentioned only once etc.

[`Array#shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) makes sense while you are looping through arguments array unless it is empty, since it removes the element from the array. In pseudocode that might look like:

```
 while opt = ARGV.shift do
   puts case opt
        when '-h' then 'Help requested'
        when '-f'
          file = ARGV.shift # requires subsequent arg
          # possible check for value is valid
          do_smth_with_file file
        ...
        end
 end
```

Comment: I know all about `optparser` but `due to me not being able to install external gems` it's not very helpful

Comment: `optparser` is not a gem, it's in the standard ruby library. You only need to require it.

Comment: Does “knowing _all_ about” include the knowledge that it is _not_ a gem, but a standard library?

Comment: @igwan I was unaware that it's standard library, I always thought it was a gem, that's awesome thank you!